# How to format groups of rows based on number sequence in Excel

Tags: excel, sequence, conditional-formatting

I have a list of data that I would like to format.

This list of data contains multiple rows and these rows belong to their own group of rows.

Example below:

```
ID|Text|SeqNo
1 |xaas|4     ~
1 |fgda|3     ~
1 |gxda|2     ~
1 |axss|1     ~
1 |sdda|2
1 |xxda|1
2 |sbeq|4     ~
2 |ssdd|3     ~
2 |dfs1|2     ~
2 |asd1|1     ~
2 |aaff|3
2 |ggff|2
2 |gdad|1
2 |ssss|2     ~
2 |srfa|1     ~
```

I want to change the formatting (fill colour) of the group of rows that belong to the sequence under `SeqNo`. They do not need to be uniquely coloured, this is for readability purposes so that it is easy to see what rows belong to what group.

I have added ~ characters next to each group (think of zebra style).

All of the rows that are grouped together with the ~ I would want formatted the same way and the rows without the ~ would be formatted the same way.

Comment: Instead of using the sequence as the identifier for the group, what if I had each row contain a unique identifier and then use that identifier to format the row?

Comment: Maybe I can create a separate column using a formula to determine if the previous row has the same value, output a 1 or 0 based on this, and then do conditional formatting based on a value of 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being relying on the tildes :)

Clear any existing CF from A:C and select A:C (assuming those are your columns) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$D1="~"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

You can either leave the "others" unformatted or apply 'standard' formatting to the entire column or columns (CF has precedence).